# Eliminar nodos de un árbol binario

Tags: c++, árboles-binarios

Se me pidió hacer una estructura de datos basada en arboles binarios, para ello debo aprovecharme de la *recursividad*.
Pero tengo un problema, y para esto debo explicarme.
Los nodos tienen la siguiente clase como estructura:

```
class node
{
private:
    int element;
    node *left, *right;
public:
    node();
    ~node();
    void SetElement(int NewElement);
    void ShowAll(bool mode);
    int GetElement();
    node*& GetLeft();
    node*& GetRight();
};
```

Donde cada nodo conoce a su hijo izquierdo y derecho, todo funciona muy bien aquí, el problema se presenta al tratar de borrar nodos, este es mi algoritmo para eliminar nodos del árbol:

```
bool BinaryTree::EraseNode(node *&TreePoint, int element)
{
    node *aux;
    bool result = false;
    if (TreePoint != NULL) //verifica que el nodo no esté vacío
    {
        if (element < TreePoint->GetElement()) //si el número es menor, se va por la izquierda
            result = EraseNode(TreePoint->GetLeft(), element);
        else if (element > TreePoint->GetElement()) //si el número es mayor, se va por la derecha
            result = EraseNode(TreePoint->GetRight(),element);
        else //Si es igual, significa que lo encontró
        {
            if (TreePoint->GetLeft() == NULL && TreePoint->GetRight() == NULL)
            { //verifica que el nodo no tenga más nodos debajo
                delete TreePoint;
                TreePoint = NULL;
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (TreePoint->GetLeft() != NULL)
                {//si tiene un nodo a la izquierda, encuentra el mayor de los menores y lo reemplaza con el que queremos borrar
                    aux = FindMajor(TreePoint->GetLeft());
                    TreePoint->SetElement(aux->GetElement());
                    result = EraseNode(aux, aux->GetElement());
                    //y vuelve a llamar al algoritmo, para eliminar el que movimos
                }
                else if (TreePoint->GetRight() != NULL)
                {//si tiene un nodo a la derecha, encuentra el menor de los mayores y lo reemplaza con el que queremos borrar
                    aux = FindMinor(TreePoint->GetRight());
                    TreePoint->SetElement(aux->GetElement());
                    result = EraseNode(aux, aux->GetElement());
                    //y vuelve a llamar al algoritmo, para eliminar el que movimos
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

En este caso `TreePoint` es un nodo del árbol, y `element` es el elemento o número que quiero borrar del árbol, cuando el nodo no está conectado a otro, no hay problema, lo borra fácil y rápido, **pero cuando hay más nodos conectados, es necesario usar de la recursividad para poder borrar y mover de su posición a todos los demás nodos para no desequilibrar el árbol, ahí se presenta el problema**; y es que cuando quiero borrar un nodo que tiene otros debajo de el, hago su respectivo `delete`, pero el nodo anterior sigue teniendo la dirección de memoria registrada, no lo pone en `NULL` y eso quiero saber como arreglarlo.

[image: esquema de un árbol binario]

DATO DE UTILIDAD: el algoritmo para borrar el árbol con el destructor funciona perfectamente y no causa errores, pero el anterior sí causa errores.

```
bool BinaryTree::EraseTree(node *&TreePoint)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (TreePoint != NULL)
    {
        result = EraseTree(TreePoint->GetLeft());
        result = EraseTree(TreePoint->GetRight());
        delete TreePoint;
        TreePoint = NULL; //<-------- Es esencial transformar el node en un NULL
        result = true;
    } 
    return result;
}
```

Algoritmo `FindMajor` que encuentra el mayor desde un punto del árbol

```
node*& BinaryTree::FindMajor(node *&TreePoint)
{
    node *aux = NULL;
    if (TreePoint != NULL)
    {
        if (TreePoint->GetRight() != NULL)
            aux = FindMajor(TreePoint->GetRight());
        else
            aux = TreePoint;
    }
    return aux;
}
```

Algoritmo `FindMinor` que encuentra el menor desde un punto del árbol

```
node*& BinaryTree::FindMinor(node *&TreePoint)
{
    node *aux = NULL;
    if (TreePoint != NULL)
    {
        if (TreePoint->GetLeft() != NULL)
            aux = FindMinor(TreePoint->GetLeft());
        else
            aux = TreePoint;
    }
    return aux;
}
```

Comment: Al borrar el nodo, con el se van todos sus hijos. la manera de recorrer un arbol binario es ir por la izquierda hasta el final y después regresarse por cada nodo y recorrer el nodo derecho.

el ultimo nodo, debe estar apuntando a Null, por ende encontrarlo no es dificil.

Comment: También pensé en eso, pero necesito una solución que haga que el propio algoritmo se encargue de resolver eso de forma recursiva.

Comment: Por lo que veo se trata de un **árbol binario de búsqueda** y quieres borrar un nodo sin borrar el resto de nodos que cuelgan de él. Ayudaría si empezaras por ahí, el compañero Mario no te entendió. Pero no me sorprende, es difícil ayudarte cuando aportas tanto código. Normalmente es mejor dar un ejemplo de código pequeño y concreto del problema que tienes.